# IO action is repeated after changin its internal value

Tags: io, monads

I try printing a value (of the showable Person type) and then changing the return type from `IO ()` to `IO Person`.

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T

data Person = Person
  { firstName :: T.Text
  , lastName :: T.Text
  } deriving Show

writePerson :: Person -> IO Person
writePerson p = const p <$> print p
```

Expected Result:

```hs
Person {firstName = "Maria", lastName = "do Rosario"}
```

Actual Result:

```hs
Person {firstName = "Maria", lastName = "do Rosario"}
Person {firstName = "Maria", lastName = "do Rosario"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running this in ghci. The first line is the output of the call to `print`. The second line is the interpreter showing the return value of the call to `writePerson`. They are identical because you pass `p` as the argument to both `const` and `print`.

Comment: How could I make ghci not return the value inside of the IO, since it is IO Person, and just one value ?

Comment: You can't. Why are you printing *and* returning the value?